# why the advanced option is removed in expo-cli on project init?

Tags: react-native, expo

I need to know about why expo-cli removed advance option while initiating a project using expo. It's available in expo-cli version 2.10.1 But if you upgraded on 2.11.x its gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an experimental feature that caused confusion for people who chose it accidentally. You can still use it with the `--workflow advanced` flag.

See the [related pull request message](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/pull/372):

> The `advanced` workflow was marked as experimental, but it seems that people sometimes choose it by mistake, which results in confusing problems [..]
>   However, you can still initialize a project using the advanced workflow, if you pass the `--workflow advanced` flag to the command.